# confusion about setting null pointers

Tags: c++

I have an array of class objects:

```
Course* courseList[100];
```

If I wanna set the CourseList to a null pointer, do I do
courseList = nullptr;
But I get an error for "expression must be a modifiable value.

For a constructor of my class ScmApp

```
ScmApp::ScmApp() {
    noOfCourses = 0;
    courseList_[100] = {};
}
```

is this the way to set all elements of courseList_ to nullptr?

Comment: No you need to loop the whole container and assign each element to be a null pointer. When this `Course* courseList(100, null);` does the same thing.

Comment: "If I wanna set the CourseList to a null pointer"  `CourseList` is not a pointer, it is an array of pointers.  Do you want to set *each element* to `nullptr`?

Comment: `courseList` is an array. You cannot set arrays to null, just like you cannot set cats or dishwashers to null. Only *pointers* can be null.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Why wouldn't `Course* courseList[100] = {nullptr};` do the job?

Comment: You don't have an array of "class objects", you have an array of pointers.

Comment: @FirstStep, That does not do the same thing. You might be thinking of a `std::vector`, in which case null pointers will be the initial value anyway.

Comment: You can't...? Oh crap I'm in so much trouble when milady discovers I nulled her cat.

Comment: @WhiZTiM: That's something very different -- that's an array that *contains* null pointers.

Comment: @chris I think I got confused. I just checked it and you are right. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you can set to a `nullptr` is, well, a pointer.

`CourseList` is not a pointer. That's the problem. That's why you can't set it to a null pointer.

`CourseList` is an array of pointers. What you can do, instead, is to set every pointer in a `CourseList` to a null pointer:

```
for (auto &p:CourseList)
    p=nullptr;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `CourseList` is a group of 100 elements and not just a single element. So you will need to iterate all the 100 and assign **each element** to be a null pointer. When this `Course* courseList[100] = {};` does the thing.

Comment: The only thing `Course* courseList(100, nullptr);` does is fail to compile.

Comment: `courseList` isn't a container, it's an array, that's why there also isn't a constructor taking 2 arguments.

Comment: I just checked it and you guys are right. My bad @molbdnilo thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Course * courseList[100] = {};
```

If you to initialize this array in your constructor use

```
std::fill(courseList, courseList + 100, nullptr);
```

or use `std::array<Course *, 100> courseList;` instead of `Course * courseList[100];`

Comment: @Andy You got several valid answers for your question. Now did you try it??

Answer (score 0):

`CourseList* courseList[100]` does not create a pointer to an array, it creates an array of pointers.  Depending on what you actually want you should be using one of the following

An array of `CourseList`s

```
CourseList courseList[100];  // possibly with = {}
courseList[0].attr = whatever;  // usage
```

Better than the above, but similar, a `std::array` of `CourseList`s

```
std::array<CourseList, 100> courseList;  // possibly with = {}
courseList[0].attr = whatever;
```

Or the closest to what it seems you want, a pointer to a `std::array` of `CourseList`s. This is probably not best, but nonetheless, here it is:

```
std::array<CourseList, 100>* courseList = nullptr;
courseList = new std::array<CourseList, 100>{};  // prefer unique_ptr
courseList->at(0).attr = whatever;
```

If you don't know the size at compile time, or want to pass around the object, your best bet is to use a `std::vector`

```
std::vector<CourseList> courseList(100);
courseList[0].attr = whatever;
```

---

Finally, the weirdest option would be to actually define a pointer to an array:

```
CourseList (*courseList)[100] = nullptr;
```

---

Addressing the update: you can just use default initializers in your class like so:

```
class ScmApp {
 private:
  CourseList* courseList[100] = {};
  int noOfCourses = 0;
};
```

But it seems like you should be using a growable container, `std::vector` and calling `push_back` to repeatedly add courses. What I see is a very hard-to-maintain keeping track of who is in what class.

If it is absolutely necessary that you take an existing array and set everything to `nullptr` then you can use `std::fill`

```
std::fill(std::begin(courseList), std::end(courseList), nullptr);
```

Comment: @Andy done, but you should be seriously rethinking your approach.